# Store a sting into a variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to store a string into a variable without saving it into a db.

For example : A user want to invite an other user with his email. The application will take this email, check if the email is related to a user.

How I can do that without created a column email into my table user_invitation.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord models can have attributes:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :other_email
end
```

Those can be assigned to and read from, but they are not saved in the database and do not require a column to map to.

However in your particular case you don't need this, you can do everything you're asking about, like:

```
def create
  @other_email = params[:other_email]

  if (User.find_by(email: @other_email))
    # Account already exists!
  else
    # It's cool.
  end
end
```

As for your invitations table you probably *do* want to store the address of the person that was invited. I usually track not only the inviting user, but the invited address and have another field for if that invitation is used, linking user A to user B through the invitations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @tadman, it's exactly what i'm looking for. But the thing that i cannot do is define the params[:other_email] as a form into my view

Comment: You're going to have to explain more about what you're doing as right now that question is super vague.

Comment: Ok, So I have a mvc company, and a model user_company. What I would like to do is create a function invite into the company controller. This function will take an email as parameter. She has to check if the email took as parameter is related to an existing user. If it's true, she will create a new user_company with the user_id and the company_id